# Draw a cumulative chart from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cost_saving': [10, 10, 20, 40, 60, 60],
                   'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})
```

How can I draw a cumulative chart of the savings?

I'm thinking of a line chart with number of items on the x-axis, and total savings on the y-axis.

The chart should show that the bulk of the savings come from a few items.

I've tried:

```
dftest['cost_saving'].plot(drawstyle='steps')
```

but it doesn't plot the cumulative values.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to add the cumulative sum no? `df['cum_sum'] = df['cost_saving'].cumsum()`?

Comment: ACtually your code works for me, what version pandas are you using? 0.18.0 works correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did:

```
df.set_index('id').cumsum()
```

And got:

```
    cost_saving
id             
a            10
b            20
c            40
d            80
e           140
f           200
```

This:

```
df.reset_index().plot.line(df.cost_saving.cumsum(), 'index', drawstyle='steps')
```

Gets me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If I want "number of items" on the x-axis, not ID, how would I do that?

Comment: What is "number of items"?  0 for 'a', 1 for 'b'?

Comment: yes exactly - so the x-axis going up to 5 (or 6, don't mind).